# Deleting Content On Module Uninstall in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I have a custom module that creates a content type on installing it. If I create a content using that content type, that content does not get deleted on uninstalling the module.

How do I delete all the contents created from that content type on uninstalling the module?

Removing the module configurations on hook_uninstall is not helping.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement the `hook_uninstall` in your `mymodule.install` file.

In this hook, you will be able to remove every content using the following code:

```
/**
* Implements hook_uninstall().
*/
function mymodule_uninstall() {
  // Load services.
  $queryFactory = \Drupal::service('entity.query')
  $nodeStorage  = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node');

  // Query all entity.
  $query = $queryFactory->get('node')
    ->condition('type', 'article'); // <-- Change the type here for yours.
  $nids = $query->execute();

  // Delete entities.
  if (!empty($nids)) {
    $entities = $nodeStorage->loadMultiple($nids);
    $nodeStorage->delete($entities);
  }
}
```

---

You could also use the `entity_delete_multiple` but this function is now deprecated. 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21entity.inc/function/entity_delete_multiple/8.2.x

---

Hope it will help you resolve your issue.

Comment: `entityManager` is also deprecated in favour of `entityTypeManager` in latest versions

Answer (score 0):

Since @Kevin-wenger answer uses `entityManager` which is deprecated.

Code using `entityTypeManager` as follows :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function MYMODULE_uninstall() {

  // Delete all nodes of given content type.
  $storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node');
  $nodes = $storage_handler->loadByProperties(['type' => 'MACHINE_NAME_OF_TYPE']);
  $storage_handler->delete($nodes);

  // Delete content type.
  $content_type = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node_type')
    ->load('MACHINE_NAME_OF_TYPE');
  $content_type->delete();
}
```

Source : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/217938